# Angular UI Router: The opposite of ui-sref-active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to achieve the opposite of [ui-sref-active="class1"](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-sref-active)? I want to insert a class on all states except for the one I define with ui-sref.

I can easily solve this on the CSS side, but I was wondering if I can do this easily with Angular UI Router as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the current uiSrefActive from [Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/stateDirectives.js#L222) and inverse the isMatch function in a new directive of your naming and add it to your link as an attribute.